# Make JPA foreign key as primary key in entity

Tags: jpa

I have a table A and table B. A has a onetomany mapping with B. In table A, I have an id field(entity class):

@Id
private Long id

In B, I have a manytoone mapping with A

@ManyToOne()
private A a;

I need to have an Id field defined in B in order to save both entities. How can I make this foreign key the primary key of B? Also for now I have added an Id field in B similar to A, but the query by Id doesn’t return any value.

Can someone please help me here?

Comment: Can you please show us how the database table look like?

Comment: You can't have a primary key that is not unique, I think. You would still have to pick `@Id` in `B` that would be unique in `B`.  I am not sure, hence this is only a comment.